# Setting Maven source in pom has no effect

Tags: java, maven

I'm afraid I've googled the hell out of this question and all answers say to just put the following into the pom:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
...
```

I need java 8's features so I put 1.8 in the above tags but when I do `mvn package` it just gives compilation errors like:

> lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5

I've tried putting the build tag before and after dependencies in the pom, changing maven compiler plugin's version (I seem to have 3.1) and removing the version tag altogether, adding the plugin also as a dependency and specifying its packaging as pom.

I've checked the versions and paths:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Also,

```
java -version
```

gives

```
java version "1.8.0"
```

And

```
mvn -version
```

displays

```
Java version: 1.8.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

Moreover, when I enable debugging info it shows it's using the 1.5 source no matter what I put in the pom:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   **(f) source = 1.5**
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   **(f) target = 1.5**
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@4648ce9
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@4648ce9
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

My last ditch guess is this is because I'm using just an unpacked mvn script which I didn't actually install (I have to specify the full path to it when I run it), which I feel would be really silly.

Also, I'm using maven within IntelliJ though I can't call that maven from commandline, perhaps their repositories/configs interfere with each other?

Comment: Are the compilation errors given by Maven itself or by IntelliJ? I don't know about IntelliJ but in Eclipse, whenever the Java version changes in the pom, the project needs to be updated so that Eclipse understands this has changed so that it can compile with the right Java version.

Comment: No, I'm getting these errors when trying to compile through command line, without any IDE.

Comment: You write _"I can't call that maven from commandline"._ Now you suddenly can?

Comment: @GeroldBroser: Not exactly, I said "I can't call *that* maven from commandline", which is maven that's used by IntelliJ, but I can call the one I downloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following properties:

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

to configure the compiler plugin.
At least with Eclipse, this works fine.

Comment: Ah, I've used those last two, but adding the java version apparently helped. Thank you!

Comment: Though it helped at the moment I'd rather not override [the System property `java.version`](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-system-properties) with a static value. This might lead to bad effects once the installed Java version changes. [`<maven.compiler.source|target>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) are just "aliases" for `<source|target>.` I think the real culprit is something else. _"I'm using just an unpacked mvn script which I didn't actually install",_ for instance.

Comment: @GeroldBroser, thanks, I'll keep in mind that this is bad practice. I'm just happy it finally works on my test machine, and on the target machine maven is already installed so hopefully it'll just work there without me having to override system config.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you include the `compilerVersion` parameter:

```
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: _[`compilerVersion`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) ... if `fork` is set to `true` ... **fork** ... **Default value is**: `false`_

Comment: @Gerold Broser Aha. That's right. Well, another try (though not really aiming to the actual cause of this strange problem) would be setting `fork=true` along with `compilerVersion=1.8`.